# How to re order rows, by moving multiple separated rows an X amount of rows below in python with either pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, rows, reindex

I have a very long dataframe with hundreds of rows. I want to select the rows with one key word in one of the columns, and lower the whole row 18 places below. Since there are too many, using reindex and doing it manually would be too long.

As an example, for this df I would like to move the rows with the word "Base" in Column A, three rows below, after "Three" :

```
A       B   C
Base    572 55
One     654 196
Two     2   156
Three   154 123
Base    78  45
One     251 78
Two     5   56
Three   321 59
Base    48  45
One     5   12
Two     531 231
Three   51  123
```

So, I want it to look like:

```
A      B    C
One    654  196
Two    2    156
Three  154  123
Base   572  55
One    251  78
Two    5    56
Three  321  59
Base   78   45
One    5    12
Two    531  231
Three  51   123
Base   48   45
```

I am new at programming, so would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

First create extra, dummy column, to mock your sorting key. In this case, as far as I understood you:

```py
ord=["One", "Two", "Three", "Base"]

df["sorting_key"]=df.groupby("A").cumcount().map(str)+":"+df["A"].apply(ord.index).map(str)
```

Then just sort by it:

```py
df.sort_values("sorting_key")
```

Result:

```py
        A    B    C sorting_key
1     One  654  196         0:0
2     Two    2  156         0:1
3   Three  154  123         0:2
0    Base  572   55         0:3
5     One  251   78         1:0
6     Two    5   56         1:1
7   Three  321   59         1:2
4    Base   78   45         1:3
9     One    5   12         2:0
10    Two  531  231         2:1
11  Three   51  123         2:2
8    Base   48   45         2:3
```

Then in order to reindex it, and drop the dummy column:

```py
df.sort_values("sorting_key").reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns="sorting_key")
```

Output:

```py
        A    B    C
0     One  654  196
1     Two    2  156
2   Three  154  123
3    Base  572   55
4     One  251   78
5     Two    5   56
6   Three  321   59
7    Base   78   45
8     One    5   12
9     Two  531  231
10  Three   51  123
11   Base   48   45
```

Comment: So the mock key is just a cumulative count per column ```A``` and index in list ord of given element in column ```A``` (so order of elements in list ord is reflecting the order we want to achieve, as a second part of out sort key). Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Thank you for explaining me.  BTW very very nice solution and good thinking. I am new to Pandas, so little difficult for me. I have segregated parts of your solution and got the overall Logic. You have made a List(which have strings in it, since we need to move `Base` at 4th position you have created indexes and then later sorted them as per their numbers, I got that. I have 1 question here, is it syntax or not sure why `.map(str)` has come 2 times? And is this `str` means we are passing string to map, will be grateful to you if you could explain it.

Comment: No worries, so ```.map(str)``` converts each element of ```pandas.Series``` into ```string``` (we are passing ```str()``` function to ```map```. This is to avoid issues with string concatenation later on (you cannot concatenate ```int``` and ```string``` otherwise).

Comment: Cool, great I got it, you ROCK.  Thanks for explaining. Any suggestions for new comer like me for any book etc(btw going through SO posts is also learning but not in a linear fashion though :) ), would request you to keep it up and keep giving good solutions, Thanks again :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I am trying this solution, but the order in which the keys get sorted is not right. In my actual dataset, I have 19 values. What I want is the order :
`
order = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,0]
`
And what I get after sorting the sorting_key is this:
0:0
0:1
0:10
0:11
0:12
0:13
0:14
0:15
0:16
0:17
0:18
0:2
0:3
0:4
0:5
0:6
0:7
0:8
0:9
`
How can I make the dozens sort in the right order, after the units?

Comment: You can left pad the second part of ```sorting_key```: ```df["sorting_key"]=df.groupby("A").cumcount().map(str)+":"+df["A"].apply(lambda x: str(ord.index(x)).zfill(3))```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
# create mask for identifying Base
mask = df.A.eq("Base")

# create index with non base values
non_base = df[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)  # reset index

# create DataFrame with Base values
base = df[mask]
base.index = base.index + (3 - np.arange(len(base)))  # change index to reflect new indices in result

# concat and sort by index
result = pd.concat([base, non_base], sort=True).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
        A    B    C
0     One  654  196
1     Two    2  156
2   Three  154  123
3    Base  572   55
4     One  251   78
5     Two    5   56
6   Three  321   59
7    Base   78   45
8     One    5   12
9     Two  531  231
10  Three   51  123
11   Base   48   45
```